# Email Regular Expression Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, validation

Can anyone correct the expression below to also not allow blank field?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="expEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="valid email address required" ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]){1,70}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: That expression is not valid btw, for example plus (+) signs will trigger an error.

Comment: It's very difficult to write a correct regexp to validate emails. The following link is supposed to be one that works for all valid emails I think, but the regexp is well over 6000 chars long...   http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: Restricting +'s really annoys me. Means you can't use googlemail filters...

Comment: I thought this might be a link worth reading for you. Its a bit of a meta discussion I picked up from HackerNews a while ago and thought it was interesting: http://davidcelis.com/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a required field validator as well - I think the regex validator will only fire if there is text in the field to look at.

Comment: The required field validator is already used in the question. The question asked by the user is to validate the regular expression written in the required field validator.

Comment: @Phani Kumar PV - Um, no it's not.  But you made me look :)

Comment: Not going to work as each error leave the space on the page for the label so the second error is floated over the right etc. Any solution to this?

Comment: @Pino - Set the display property on the validator to dynamic.

Answer (score 18):

One of the solutions (not a best one) is to implement some regular expression:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$
```

Sample: *someone@example.com*

But actually, it's very hard to write and maintain a good email validation regexp. You shouldn't trust 100% your regex. You can find several articles about that difficulty on the Internet:

- [It's Impossible to Validate an Email Address (elliot.land) - discussion on Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11414749)
- [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)
- [Email Address Regular Expression That 99.99% Works.](http://emailregex.com/)

Comment: This fails with a valid email of `bob_@hotmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an additional validator - [`asp:RequiredFieldValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28VS.90%29.aspx)

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Message!" />
```

Any of  ASP.NET 2.0 validators based on [`BaseValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.basevalidator%28VS.90%29.aspx) (except RequiredFieldValidator itself of course) doesn't checks specified field to be empty.

Btw, to make custom `UserControl` being able to be checked with such validators, use

```
[System.Web.UI.ValidationProperty("PropertyName")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make something like

```
if (txtEmail.Text.Trim().length > 0) then
       validate
```

I think that since regular expressions are rather complex, anything that can be done outside the regular expression should be done outside the regular expression, this should make the code more readable, but that is just me.

Your regular expression is quite complex, [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) you should find a simpler one. 
Anyways, what you can do is something like this:      ^(regex){1}$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat this field as required one then it is better go for RequiredFieldValidator.

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqEmail" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email address required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Another choice is to use .net **CustomValidator**, set its **ValidateEmptyText** to **True**, and for email address validation you can use a JavaScript function which will be specified in **ClientValidationFunction** property of validator.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uNameExpr = "^[a-zA-Z](.{1,9})$";
    string phoneExpr = 
        "((\\(\\d{3}\\) ?)|(\\d{3}-))?\\d{3}-\\d{4}";

    // Define validation expressions.
    RegExprVal1.ValidationExpression = uNameExpr;
    RegExprVal2.ValidationExpression = phoneExpr;

    ReqFldVal1.Text = "User name is required";
    RegExprVal1.Text = "Must be between 2 to 10 characters";
    RegExprVal2.Text = "Please provide a valid number: (425) 555-0187";
    // ErrorMessages appear in ValidationSummary.
    RegExprVal1.ErrorMessage = "Incorrect UserName format. Name" +
        " can be 2 to 10 characters long";
    ReqFldVal1.ErrorMessage = "User name required";
    RegExprVal2.ErrorMessage = 
        "Please provide a valid number: (000) 000-0000";
}

void OnCmdClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        ActiveForm = Form2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with simply using `Regex` class in `System.Text.RegularExpressions`:

```
private bool ValidateEmail()
{
    string email = txtemail.Text;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
    Match match = regex.Match(email);
    if (match.Success)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Comment: what about .info domains?  This highlights why regexes are bad.  It is also technically valid not need at dot in the last part, if you run a country's DNS, you can be bob@ly.  Then you can also have emails at sub-domains, bob@foo.lemon.bar.ac.uk.  So this regex doesn't cover it.